# An extra dot in the tour of the site

Tags: bug, status-completed

The "elevator pitch" of this site in the [tour](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) has a typo: the first sentence ends with two dots..

> [image]

The reason is that the string describing the audience of the site ends with a period, which it should not:

> "users of Linux, FreeBSD and other Un*x-like operating systems."

This string is also returned by the [API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/sites#pagesize=999&filter=!.UDMsvaYdFr.b0xP&run=true) and appears in the Site Switcher in the top bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra dot has been DESTROYED!!  Thanks for the report..